# Make iOS App having functionality same as Excel Sheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, excel, vba, macros

I have an excel sheet .xlsm that contains formulas and macros which are currently used for some calculations. It is basically an app built into excel. All I need to do is to convert this excel file to an app that can run on iPad.

The problem is that has dropdowns, checkboxes and lots of formulas written in it and in formulas, there are references to the cells and functions in excel that is really confusing me to trace out what is really happening when I input some value in some cell. Also, the VBA project associated with it is password protected.

Is there any way using which I can convert the functionality of this excel file to an app for iOS.

Comment: if you know how to do this, you could start a company :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an apple developer account and the password for the protected vba you mention?  There are companies out there and programers out there that do exactly this stuff.

My opinion, if it is worth anything, is that your focus today should not be on just putting a round peg into a square hole, but to instead focus on your comment here: "cells and functions in excel that is really confusing me to trace out what is really happening" as it may help in your future development.

The shorter route is to just google your exact question, and I found about a dozen different programs or groups that do exactly what you are asking. Like, 'kintone', 'DronaHQ', 'slideshare' etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could replicate a similar function using kintone. 
The cloud service itself allows you to build simple databases (you can imagine 1 "kintone App" as 1 sheet of your excel) using drag and drop, including field types like drop-downs and check-boxes. 
[An example gif of building the database on kintone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elEBT.gif)

There's also a calculation field in kintone that allows some simple calculation formulas to be written in relation to other columns. If though your calculation is too complex for kintone to handle, you can also [apply JavaScript to your kintone App](https://developer.kintone.io/hc/en-us/articles/213149757/) to handle those for you.

The kintone App itself is built on the desktop, but once it's made, you can access it via the kintone Mobile app for iOS/Android, or via your phone browser.

I should note though, that this does not equal to "Creating an iPhone app that can be listed in the App Store". It just creates an access point on the web, where you can access your "kintone App" by punching it's URL into your browser (or access it directly using the kintone iPhone App). A password and username will be needed to access this url.